# How to prevent user control to be cached

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, visual-studio-2005

in my web application i am facing a issue after making it live. i am facing issue of caching.
i have a menu usercontrol on master page. some menus are opening same page with different parameters.

the issue i am facing is that when a page is opened and i click on menu to open another page or same page with different id. that it select menu item for new page but not deselect menu of last opened page.
i think its because of caching. please tell me how to prevent menu user control of my web application to be cached.

thanks

Comment: What makes you think it is caching? A code snippet would help.

Comment: @Xavier: because of its ambiguous behavior.some times it works properly but some times it not deselects old control. and the issue i am facing is only on live. on my development environment its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell if it is a caching issue, but have you tried setting [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) on your user control?

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound like caching per-se.  It sounds more like you have an issue with postback. The control is remembering its last setting after the round trip to the server.

Comment: actually we are using web farming and on load balancer our pages get cached.